# Can a person travel using their i94 as an ID?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-free-entry

my brother in law recently was admitted to this our country and after spending a few days at his ort of entry with family now wishes to make his way up to his final destination. can i reserve him a plane ticket knowing he only has his i94 at this point?

Comment: What is "this our country"?

Comment: Presumably he has a passport since he just arrived from abroad. Why would you think he cannot use his passport to make his way to his final destination?

Comment: Yes you can book a ticket.  Assuming the I94 refers to te US immigration form, domestic flight bookings only require a name to reserve and only a photo ID (such as the passport) to fly.

Answer (score 3):

Physical I94's are no longer given for persons entering by air - it's all electronic. So at best your brother-in-law has a printout of his I94 information from the CBP website.

To answer your specific question, no, an I94 can not be used for 'ID'. It contains no photograph, and is nothing more than a printout from a website.

However I suspect the question you're really asking is does he require any additional documentation from immigration in order to travel domestically within the US - in which case the answer is NO.

In order to travel within the US, he will require a valid form of identification - which generally means either a US-issued drivers license (which I presume he does not have), or a valid Passport (which he obviously does have!). No additional immigration screening will occur when flying domestically, so even the I94 itself is not required.

Comment: paper I94 are still given if you enter the US by car/bus/train

Comment: Which is why I explicitly said "... for persons entering by air"